# OperationCanceledException from http request when Xamarin.iOS app asking permissions

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification, httprequest, httpclient

I have a problem with a Xamarin.iOS app. On startup I send request to the server for authorization. In the same time app asks user about permissions to send they notifications. And it looks like the app gone to foreground and brake the connection with OperationCanceledException. By this problem I can't auth user. For workaround I made second request when catch OperationCanceledException. And because of this sometimes users are authorize twice. How I can send request without cancellation in this situations?

```
    private async Task<string> PostAndHandleHttpRequestAsync(Dictionary<string, string> content)
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(15000); 
        CancellationToken token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        var newClient = new HttpClient();
        var contentSerialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
        try
        {
            var postAsyncResult = await newClient.PostAsync(GlobalSettings.urlToPHP, new StringContent(contentSerialize), token);
            var responseBody = await postAsyncResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseBody;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException c)
        {
            // onetime retry
            if (cancellationCounter == 0)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("second");
                cancellationCounter = 1;
                var postAsyncResult = await newClient.PostAsync(GlobalSettings.urlToPHP, new StringContent(contentSerialize), token);
                var responseBody = await postAsyncResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseBody;
            }
            else
            {
                cancellationCounter = 0;
                return "Cancel";
            }
            return "Cancel";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error PostAndHandleHttpRequestAsync " + e.Message);
            return "Error";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could post the request again when the App enter from background to foreground .

#### in AppDelegate.cs

```
public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication application)
        {
            base.WillEnterForeground(application);

            if(!UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13,0))
            {
                NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("willActive", null);
            }          
        }
```

#### in SceneDelegate

```
[Export ("sceneWillEnterForeground:")]
public void WillEnterForeground (UIScene scene)
{
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("willActive",null);

    // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
    // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
}
```

#### in your ViewController

```
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(new NSString("willActive"),(notification)=> {
        
           if (cancellationCounter == 1)
            {
                //request again
            }
        
        });

    }


    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(this, "willActive");

    }
```

```
catch (OperationCanceledException c)
{
    cancellationCounter =1;
}
```